# Azure project doens't work in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I try to upgrade the project from VS2010 to VS2012 I receive this error:

This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them:

NimbleSchedule.Azure.CloudService

Azure project works correctly on VS 2010

Did anyone experience this problem?
How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. We need to install Windows Azure SDK exactly for VS 2012. I just went to Add -> New project. Then I've selected Azure SDK and VS 2012 told me that I should install SDK fro VS 2012. I followed the link which VS 2012 proposed and through Web Installer I installed Azure SDK for VS 2012